# Output Array to Specific Worksheet in Excel uisng PowerShell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, powershell

I have an array in PowerShell called "$OutArray"
The array is filled with multiple emails that I need to output into each cell in Excel in the very first column.  The sheet is labeled "Reporters".

I use the following for loop to try to output each item in the array:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excel_file_path)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.Item("Reporters")
$ExcelWorkSheet.activate()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $OutArray.Length; $i++) {
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1) = $OutArray[$i]
}
```

Btw, $excel_file_path is already declared properly.

However, I receive the following error:

[image: PowerShell Error]

I was able to output the array in a new workbook by the following command:

```
$OutArray | out-file "C:\desiredPathHere"
```

but I'm trying to append to an existing workbook in a new sheet.

Any hints?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is caused by trying to index into one-based array used by Excel as if though it was zero-based:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $OutArray.Length; $i++) {
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(($i + 1), 1) = $OutArray[$i]
}
```

Or, to avoid aggravating the fragile Excel COMObject:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le $OutArray.Length; $i++) {
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1) = $OutArray[$i-1]
}
```